# Side nav bar overlap the component

Tags: angular

I created a fixed side-nav bar in my angular project.All the Other Component rendered beneath nav bar.how to slove that.
 [image]

SideNav Component Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="../../assets/hotel (3).png" alt="Logo">
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Infomation</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#"> Procedures</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="/doctor">Hellow</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Chat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Books</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

SideNav.Css

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;

}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 0px 0px;
  border-color: lightgrey;

}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20% 0;

}
```

app-compnent.html

```
<app-sidemenu>

  <div class="view">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

I want to fill that empty area with my  other component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your side bar component and main content in a container, and apply `flex-grow: 1` to the main content, this will make it take all space left:

```css
/*Apply CSS reset*/ 
*{
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Declare layout*/
.container{
 display: flex;
}

aside {
 width:150px;
 height: 100vh;
 background:green;
}

.view {
 flex-grow: 1;
 height: 100vh;
 background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <aside>Your navbar component</aside>
   <div class="view">
      ...Your router-outlet
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it help, would you might mark it as corrected and upvote if it worked ?